# Unable to install gmum.r package

Tags: r, svm, libsvm

I'am not able to install the R package `gmum.r`. It says compilation failed. I have installed all supporting packages.

```
/bin/bash: g++: command not found

make: *** [svm/libsvm_runner.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gmum.r’
* removing ‘/home/XXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/gmum.r’
```

Comment: You must provide the full toolchain, including the correct compiler. This will depend on your OS.

Comment: Edited broken code highlighting, this should increase readability. Also: Added the libsvm tag as this is related to libsvm not only to SVMs in general.

Comment: Thanks :) Iam using ubuntu 14.04. I have installed g++ compiler. now i arise an error like ,                                                                                                          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llzma
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gmum.r.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gmum.r’
* removing ‘/home/XXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/gmum.r’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got worked using the following command,

**sudo apt-get install r-base-dev**

Errors fixed !